# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing nn_parser: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, nlp, spacy

Just connected to a gcp instance. Installed Python, VScode, git. Cloned my repository create a virtual environment. All OK till now. Then I ran my project.

But got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "C:\Users\hiteshsom\Documents\hobby_project\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import pipeline
  File "C:\Users\hiteshsom\Documents\hobby_project\env\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing nn_parser: The specified module could not be found.
```

This error did not come in my local.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more information on `python` and `spacy` version installed on your instance?

Comment: `python`: 3.8.4
`spacy`: 2.3.2

Comment: GCP instance OS was windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Please try installing `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` and run `python -c "import spacy"` to see it helps. If this doesn't help, you can try installing `spacy` via conda.